# Como sumar y restar dentro de console.log

Tags: javascript

No puedo encontrar info de como sumar o restar dentro de `console.log` ya que el `+` y el `-` no los toma como tales.

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], edita y muestra que llevas hecho

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let a = 20;
let b = 14;

// Suma
console.log(a + b);

// Resta
console.log(a - b);

// Con string al principio
console.log("Resultado: " + (a + b));
```

Comment: Se agradece el apoyo pero sería bueno mínimo esperar a conocer que código lleva el OP y a partir de ahi poderlo guiar